# cumulative sum with calculation sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like:

[image: tblCustomer]

Now I want the table like

```
Date        Description     Debit      Credit     Balance
-----------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-11  xxx             25000.00              -25000.00
2017-05-11  aaa                        20000.00    -5000.00
2017-05-12  xyz             5000.00               -10000.00
2017-06-01  abc                        10000.00        0.00
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th> Date</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2017-05-11</td>
    <td>xxx</td>
    <td>25000.00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-25000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2017-05-11</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>20000.00</td>
    <td>-5000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2017-05-12</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>5000.00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-10000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2017-06-01</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>10000.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please don't use SQL 2012 keywords like partition by, rows unbound preceding etc. Because I want it in SQL Server 2008.

I have done it in 2012, looks like:

```
SELECT  [Date], 
        [Description], 
        ( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Dr' THEN Amount END ) AS Debit, 
        ( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Cr' THEN Amount END ) AS Credit, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Dr' THEN - Amount ELSE Amount END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DATE ) AS Balance
FROM tblCustomer
WHERE CustomerID = '1'
```

Comment: Time to upgrade perhaps? 2008 has been out of mainstream support for nearly 3 years!!

Comment: Whats wrong with your query. this will run on SQL2008 as well

Comment: @JaydipJ no, it will not run on sql server < 2012, it has running sum, an *aggregation* that user *ordr by* in the partition clause

Comment: It may solve using inner join but the main problem is:- there is no unique field, how to solve in this case?

Comment: On SQL Sever 2008 the most efficient solution for running sum is using cursor. I can give you a set-based solution but its performance is very bad

Comment: Does your table have 1 customer or many? Your final output has no customer

Comment: there can be more than 1 customer but the output is for a customer at a time.

Comment: @sepupic yes it is better to use 'while'  than 'cursor' in proc. or func. but is there any single query to solve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149203/discussion-between-darpan-dahal-and-sepupic).

Comment: partition by and order by are valid in sql server 2008 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

Comment: @Jayvee, you do not distinguish window RANKING functions and AGGREGATING functions. Order by in partition clause for AGGREGATING functions has appeared in SQL Server 2012 only

Comment: @sepupic good point, I hadn't read the question properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a set-based solution for getting the result as you want, you did not answer if you want also to group by CustomerId, so I did not include it as your result set does not contain it:

```
    declare @t table (dt date, descr varchar(100), drcr char(2), am decimal(10,2));
    insert into @t values
    ('20170511', 'xxx', 'Dr', 25000), 
    ('20170511', 'aaa', 'Cr', 20000), 
    ('20170512', 'xyz', 'Dr', 5000), 
    ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000), 
    ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000);


    with cte as
    (
    select dt, descr, 
           Debit, Credit,
           am_signed,
           row_number() over(order by dt, Credit) as rn
    from @t cross apply
         (
           select
           case drcr 
                when 'Dr' then am
           end as Debit,

           case drcr 
                when 'Cr' then am
           end as Credit,

           case drcr 
                when 'Dr' then -am
                when 'Cr' then am
           end as am_signed

         )a
    )       

    ,cte1 as
    (
    select t1.dt, t1.descr, t1.Debit, t1.Credit, t1.am_signed,
           sum(t2.am_signed) as balance, t1.rn
    from cte as t1 
         join cte as t2 
             on t2.rn <= t1.rn
    group by t1.dt, t1.descr, t1.Debit, t1.Credit, t1.am_signed, t1.rn
    )

    select dt, descr, Debit, Credit, balance
    from cte1
    order by rn;
```

..................................................................

To @Jayvee: check [How to Use Microsoft SQL Server 2012's Window Functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1):

> SQL Server 2012 (formerly code-named SQL Server Denali) introduces
>   several important T-SQL programmability features; this article focuses
>   on one of those features—window functions. **SQL Server 2005** was the
>   first milestone in supporting window functions; it **introduced window
>   ranking functions** (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, and NTILE), as well
>   as **limited support for window *aggregate* functions—*only with a window
>   partition clause***. **SQL Server 2012 enhances support for window
>   *aggregate functions* by introducing window *order*** and frame ***clause***s,
>   support for offset functions (LAG, LEAD, FIRST_VALUE, and LAST_VALUE),
>   and support for window distribution functions (PERCENT_RANK,
>   CUME_DIST, PERCENTILE_DISC, and PERCENTILE_CONT).

Comment: Sorry my window was refreshed now and I see you answered about CustomerId. If you output 1 customer at a time, this solution is right, I mean, the input is already filtered by CustomerId so it's fine. For 1 Customer at a time the performance is not so bad, so you have no need to use cursor

Comment: Thanks! but still problem if input values are same in different rows suppose: insert into @t values
    ('20170511', 'xxx', 'Dr', 25000),
    ('20170511', 'aaa', 'Cr', 20000),
    ('20170512', 'xyz', 'Dr', 5000),
    ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000),
 ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000);

Comment: @Darpan Dahal, now I see, I couldn't imagine you have totally identical rows, I can resolve this but wouldn't it be better to aggregate those rows in 1 before doing the main calcutaltion? If it's not aceptable, wait a minute I'll chenge the code

Comment: @Darpan Dahal, I've updated my answer, there is nothing new in it, I've added row_number there even in my first answer to permit the calculation to start from the row with NULL in Credit field, now I just use it for another purpose: for not aggregatin identical rows into 1 row

Comment: Finally, Thank you very much for the solution. Exactly what I need. Actually, I have selected data from multiple tables with union all and the table provided above is for the sample only. So, there can be same data in multiple rows. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with tc as
    (salect *, row_number() over(order by date, CrDR) as rownum)


    SELECT  [Date], 
            [Description], 
            ( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Dr' THEN Amount END ) AS Debit, 
            ( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Cr' THEN Amount END ) AS Credit, 
            select (SUM( CASE WHEN DrCr = 'Dr' THEN - Amount ELSE Amount END ) from tc tc1 where tc1.rownum<=tc.rownum) AS Balance
    FROM tblCustomer tc
    WHERE CustomerID = '1'
```

if you want multiple customers you can add a tc1.customerid=tc.customerid to the subquery

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with your help. My code is like:

```
declare @t table (dt date, descr varchar(100), drcr char(2), am decimal(10,2));
    insert into @t values
    ('20170511', 'xxx', 'Dr', 25000), 
    ('20170511', 'aaa', 'Cr', 20000), 
    ('20170512', 'xyz', 'Dr', 5000), 
    ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000), 
    ('20170601', 'abc', 'Cr', 10000);
```

`with cte as
(
select dt, descr, 
     (case when drcr='Dr' then  am end)as  Debit, 
     (case when drcr='Cr' then am end) as Credit,
     (case when drcr='Dr' then -am 
            when drcr='Cr' then am end)as tot,
       row_number() over(order by dt, drcr ) as rn
       from @t
 )
 select c.dt,c.descr,c.Debit,c.Credit,sum(c1.tot)as Balance from cte c inner join cte c1
 on c1.rn<=c.rn 
 group by c.rn,c.dt,c.descr,c.Debit,c.Credit 
 order by c.dt`

and final output is: [image]